# MagicEden Create Pool Usage Problem

Tags: magiceden

I want to send an offer using the Magiceden API. Below is the code example I use. When I compile the code, it appears in Solana Explorer but not in Magiceden. Does anyone know where I made a mistake?

API Docs : https://docs.magiceden.io/reference/get_instructions-mmm-create-pool

CODE :

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const { Keypair, Connection, Transaction, SystemProgram, sendAndConfirmTransaction } = require('@solana/web3.js');

const solanaRpcUrl = 'https://api.mainnet-beta.solana.com';
const privateKey = Uint8Array.from(PRIVITE_KEY);
const fromWallet = Keypair.fromSecretKey(privateKey);

const connection = new Connection(solanaRpcUrl, 'confirmed');

const requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: {
    accept: 'application/json',
    authorization: 'Bearer API_TOKEN'
  }
};

const fetchUrl = 'https://api-mainnet.magiceden.dev/v2/instructions/mmm/create-pool?spotPrice=307499986&curveType=exp&curveDelta=0&reinvestBuy=false&reinvestSell=false&lpFeeBp=0&buysideCreatorRoyaltyBp=10000&paymentMint=11111111111111111111111111111111&collectionSymbol=bonkznft&owner=BFEfL26iALmGbCZUJmbRFPzBPyaEqBwH7nDMvFviBvs7';

fetch(fetchUrl, requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(async response => {
    const transaction = new Transaction().add(
      SystemProgram.transfer({
        fromPubkey: fromWallet.publicKey,
        toPubkey: 'BFEfL26iALmGbCZUJmbRFPzBPyaEqBwH7nDMvFviBvs7',
        lamports: 5000,
      })
    );

    const signature = await sendAndConfirmTransaction(
      connection,
      transaction,
      [fromWallet]
    );

    console.log(`SUCCESS. SIGNATURE: ${signature}`);
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```